# Re-upload or add back icloud backup apps

Tags: icloud, backup

Is there a way to manually re-add apps to iCloud backup. I subscribe to the 50GB service and I always have 37GB free, which seems a waste.

Is it possible to add some apps back into the upload process, seems useless you can't do from the phone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204247), you can add apps to iCloud backup on the iPhone this way:

> ## Select which iOS apps to back up
>
> Many apps automatically back up to iCloud after you install them. You can change which apps back up to iCloud and remove existing backups from your storage.
>
> ### Use these steps on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch:
>
> 1.Tap `Settings > iCloud`.
>       *  If you're using iOS 8 or later, tap `Storage > Manage Storage`.
>       *  If you're using an earlier version of iOS, tap `Storage & Backup > Manage Storage`.
>     2.Tap the name of your iOS device.
>     3. Under Backup Options, turn on any apps that you want to back up.